# Automatically insert empty base method bodies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

If I have a base class with some abstract methods, is there a way to let Visual Studio automatically insert the empty bodies of the methods that need to be implemented for me in new derived classes (like you can with Eclipse and Java)?

Like so:

```
public abstract class foo
{
    public virtual void bar()
    {
       doSomething();
    }
}

public class Derived : foo
{
    //somehow tell VS to insert this without me having to write everything
    public override void bar()
    {
       base.bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an 'Implement Abstract Class' in the right-click menu when clicking on the abstract class name but that might be from Resharper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes and No, to some extent.

1- If the base class is abstract then when VS will show a smart tag which provide stub implementations for all the abstract methods, but not the virtual methods. This is the same for implementing interfaces.

[image]

2- For virtual methods, you do not need to type everything. In the derived class you can just type the `override` keyword and then select the relevant method to override from the intellisense list. The list will filter to the methods that do not already have overrides within the class.

Comment: +1 for point 2. I was hunting high and low for this trick. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for saving lot time.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is a way to generate an implemented methods, but with different body, that contains

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Right click in VisualStudio over the interface -> ImplementInterface

Answer (score 1):

You can have Visual Studio implement an interface automatically. But to add method stubs for virtual methods all at once cannot be done. You have to start writing *override* to have IntelliSense give you a list of overridabl methods.

I think the main reason why there is no such feature is because you do not need to override the methods. Whereas when implementing an interface you have to implement all methods to fulfill the requirements created by the interface.